# error select in select query on codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, postgresql

i have problems. This is my code. when I run this code in **navicat**, **no errors** and the results I want to perform.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ON (t1.rl3_11_tahun) t1.rl3_11_tahun,
    t1.rl3_11_id,
    t2.rl3_11_terapi
FROM
    formulir_rl3_11 t1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        rl3_11_tahun,
        SUM (rl3_11_terapi) rl3_11_terapi
    FROM
        formulir_rl3_11
    GROUP BY
        rl3_11_tahun
) t2 ON t1.rl3_11_tahun = t2.rl3_11_tahun
WHERE
    t1.rl3_11_tahun = '2014'
```

**BUT** when I type this code in CodeIgniter, I get a lot of errors. this my code in codeigniter.

```
> $this->db->select("DISTINCT ON(t1.rl3_11_tahun)
> t1.rl3_11_tahun,t1.rl3_11_id, t2.rl3_11_terapi ",FALSE)
>        ->FROM ('formulir_rl3_11 t1')
>        ->JOIN('(SELECT rl3_11_tahun, SUM(rl3_11_terapi) rl3_11_terapi FROM formulir_rl3_11 GROUP BY rl3_11_tahun ) t2','t1.rl3_11_tahun =
> t2.rl3_11_tahun WHERE ti.rl3_11_tahun=2014');
> $query = $this->db->get();     
> return $query->result();
```

This is error when i write this code in codeigniter

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ti" LINE 3: ...N "t1"."rl3_11_tahun" = "t2"."rl3_11_tahun" WHERE ti.rl3_11_... ^

SELECT DISTINCT ON(t1.rl3_11_tahun) t1.rl3_11_tahun, t1.rl3_11_id, t2.rl3_11_terapi FROM "formulir_rl3_11" t1 JOIN (SELECT rl3_11_tahun, SUM(rl3_11_terapi) rl3_11_terapi FROM formulir_rl3_11 GROUP BY rl3_11_tahun ) t2 ON "t1"."rl3_11_tahun" = "t2"."rl3_11_tahun" WHERE ti.rl3_11_tahun=2014

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rsaj_report_ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

What's wrong with my code? how to convert that code from navicat to codeigniter?
    can anybody help me? Sorry for my english. 
    Thank you so much for your answers!

Regards, Rahmat!

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: This error that i get.A Database Error Occurred

Error Number:

ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "ti" LINE 3: ...N "t1"."rl3_11_tahun" = "t2"."rl3_11_tahun" WHERE ti.rl3_11_... ^

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT ON(t1.rl3_11_tahun) t1.rl3_11_tahun, t1.rl3_11_id, t2.rl3_11_terapi FROM "formulir_rl3_11" t1 JOIN (SELECT rl3_11_tahun, SUM(rl3_11_terapi) rl3_11_terapi FROM formulir_rl3_11 GROUP BY rl3_11_tahun ) t2 ON "t1"."rl3_11_tahun" = "t2"."rl3_11_tahun" WHERE ti.rl3_11_tahun=2014

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\rsaj_report_ci\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Comment: [Edit] your question and add those errors in the question itself

Comment: I've updated my question above. please help me.

Comment: @wiracode - is it case sensitive? And do you need to call both `from()` and `where()` explicitly? I don't know much about CI, but the manual does it that way.

Answer (score 0):

What about use codeigniter Queries function? not the Active Record Class?

```
$this->db->query('YOUR QUERY HERE');
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html